Inline stylesheets not reflected applied by emotion(mui) in Next.js project only in Chrome
Classes from Inline stylesheets generated by emotion(MUI) are not getting applied. Facing issue only in latest Chrome (v129) working for other browsers and even for Chrome (version <=128).
I have attached two screenshots,
In Screenshot 1, I have taken an example of class(emotion) applied to svg element is getting reflected in styles hence styles are getting applied where as in Screenshot 2 same class is not getting reflected in styles hence it is not working and it is happenig for other HTML elements such as fieldset.
Case: Working (Chrome <= v128, Safari, Firefox, Brave)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZbFVakFu_2lOFIGiIOmX7UocT0tZaZjc/view?usp=drive_link
Case: Not Working (Only in Chrome v129)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DfeoHLEdBB27QDGnKtya7HQivVDC6rm1/view?usp=drive_link
Can anyone help with the possible solution?
Relavant Tech Stack
Next.js: v13
MUI: v5.14
OS Specifications
OS: macOS Sequoia (v15.0)
I've tried across multiple browsers and Chrome<=v128, working correctly for me but not working only in Chrome v129 as expected as I mentioned above.

Having the same issue in our app using NextJS and styled-components

Following https://chromium.googlesource.com/playground/chromium-org-site/+/refs/heads/main/for-testers/command-line-flags.md and running /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --js-flags=--no-maglev-optimistic-peeled-loops fixes the bug for me.
from https://issues.chromium.org/issues/367758074
Update: Fixed on Chrome new release (129.0.6668.71)

Thanks @Colo Ghidini. it was helpful!

we are seen the same inssue in our website
doing a research we have found the root of the issue, the chrome update,
to fix this we have added the emotion cache and disabled speedy
here for reference
https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/3256
update:
the fix is already live in google chrome new version
https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/v8/v8/+/5887185
